# U-SQL Catalog metadata views

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In the mature RDBMS world we have a lot of catalog views that describe metadata and can be used for codegeneration of mainenance scripts.

Does it exists something like this in U-SQL? For example i wanna generate U-SQL script that create statistics for some columns in some U-SQL tables.

```
SELECT 
   'CREATE STATISTICS st__' + t.name + '_' + c.name + ' ON ' + t.name + '(' + 
c.name + ') WITH FULLSCAN;'
FROM
   sys.tables t
       INNER JOIN
   sys.columns c ON t... = c....
```

It will generate me a script that will create statistics for me. Does it exists these system views?

(although looks like i can use powershell API, but i'm not sure if it powerfull enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Powershell scripts are supposed to provide you with all the information to allow you to generate such scripts. If something is missing or not working, please let us know.

We have catalog views on our roadmap for later this year.

Answer (score 2):

Catalog views are now available, please see [Catalog Views (U-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt826850.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
$adlaAccount = "myacc";
$tablePath = "dbname.schemaname";

$tables = Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogItem -Account $adlaAccount -ItemType Table -Path $tablePath
ForEach ($t in $tables)
{
    ForEach ($c in $t.ColumnList)
    {
        "CREATE STATISTICS st__$($t.Name)__$($c.Name) ON $($t.name)($($c.Name)) WITH FULLSCAN;"
    }
}
```